# Copying only part of a file to another one without losing encoding

Tags: shell, file, encoding, character-encoding

i have some files with some bad character in the first line, so i want to put in a new files lines from 2nd to last one.

```
#get number of line of the file
wc -l filename
#copy in a new file from line 2 to the end
sed -n '2,6p' filename > newfile
```

This works fine but it changes the way the file is encoded; in fact if i do some file -i i get this result:

```
#original file encoding
file -i filename
text/plain; charset=utf-16le

#newfile encoding
file -i newfile
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: why don't you copy the file and remove that line?

Comment: i tried sed -i '1d' newfile, but encoding is changed again... i'm starting to think that characters on first line are someway related to encoding...

Comment: Could you provide a sample file so we can play around with it?

Comment: i'm afraid i can't (because of privacy policies)... in the end i had to solve my problem by converting the file using iconv.

`iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF8 filename`